# How to auto increment in phpmydamin with custom number and character string

Tags: mysql

How can I set my custom value in auto increment column when insert query fire in phpMyAdmin

I want like when I insert a data in MySQL at that time the auto increment column value add with like something ABC001 and next record will be ABC002

It there any way to setup this functionality

This is my table structure

[image]

I want new code for every insert query for red mark field

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a TRIGGER like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `setDrinkk` BEFORE INSERT ON `yourTable` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       SET NEW.DrinkCode = CONCAT('ABC-', LPAD(NEW.db_id,4,'0'));
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add 2 more fields to the table..One field(eg:`drink_text`)containing the text 'ABC' and other field (Eg:`drink_no`) with autoincrement.

Set default value of `drink_text` as ABC.

Set `autoincrement primary key` for `drink_no`

`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=101;`

Now in insert query you have to concatenate both the fields to `drink_code`

```
//your insert query
INSERT INTO tablename( user_id,club_id) VALUES ('xyz','abc');
//drink_code with custom string
UPDATE tablename SET drink_code = concat( drink_text, drink_no ) ;
```

Comment: i want using trigger