# How vl i autoincrement the string in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

How can I autoincrement the value column `attachment_path` as image1, image2.... where the type is `VARCHAR`
can this be done using php code or achieved directly in phpmyadmin

[image]

Comment: am not able to post the pic of database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to auto increment in phpmydamin with custom number and character string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107203/how-to-auto-increment-in-phpmydamin-with-custom-number-and-character-string)

Comment: can i do it using php....

Comment: There is no `email_attachment` column

Comment: am so sry.. fr the partial question, n wrong column name...

Comment: want to increment the column attachment_path with image1, image2,.. so on....in phpmyadmin...!! can this be done by php code or can be achieved directly in database..

Answer (score 0):

I edited the answer to be suitable for your case from the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107203/how-to-auto-increment-in-phpmydamin-with-custom-number-and-character-string) mentioned before.

You'll have to add 2 more fields to the table..

1. (eg:`image_text`) containing the text 'Image'
2. (eg:`image_num`) with autoincrement

Set default value of `image_text` as 'Image'.

Set `autoincrement primary key` for `image_num`

`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=101;`

Don't forget to delete the existing `attachment_path` column.

```
UPDATE tablename SET attachment_path = concat( image_text, image_num ) ;
```